# HtmlUnit isn't working with Javascript enable in selenium API

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to use javascript enabled HtmlUnit webdriver under selenium API but I get these awful errors. Htmlunit without javascript works on the website just to connect and read direct data, but when it comes to click and select a menu javascript is necessary.

[errors http://s8.postimg.org/n3tgfau1v/selnium.jpg](http://s8.postimg.org/n3tgfau1v/selnium.jpg)

http://s8.postimg.org/n3tgfau1v/selnium.jpg

I would really like to get HtmlUnit to work since its like 1000 or 10000 or even more faster that firefox webdriver... Would one have some ideas on this problem ?

Comment: If you need headless browser for testing, why not use PhantomJs?

Comment: mmmh I don't know phantomJS I'll have a look